# Returning a pandas Series of strings that contain strings from a list

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas Series with sentences and a list of words. I want to return all entries in the Series that contain all the words in the list

eg.

```
sample_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat']

Series
0 "I have a dog, a cat, and a rat."
1 "I only have a dog."
2 "I only have a cat."
```

In this example only the first row would be returned.

I am currently using the .str.contains() function for each word in the list. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**

```
In [1413]: s
Out[1413]: 
0    I have a dog, a cat, and a rat.
1                 I only have a dog.
2                 I only have a cat.
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

---

A bullet-proof method would involve iterating over `sample_list` and building a new dataframe using the `pd.DateFrame` constructor. You can then call `df.min` to get your final mask:

```
In [1426]: pd.DataFrame([s.str.contains(x) for x in sample_list]).T.min(axis=1)
Out[1426]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Apply `boolean indexing` on the series:

```
In [1427]: idx = pd.DataFrame([s.str.contains(x) for x in sample_list]).T.min(axis=1); s[idx]
Out[1427]: 
0    I have a dog, a cat, and a rat.
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

---

If you can guarantee that words in `sample_list`appear in the same order in those columns, you can use a single `str.contains` call with `regex=True`:

```
In [1414]: idx = s.str.contains('.*'.join(sample_list), regex=True); s[idx]
Out[1414]: 
0    I have a dog, a cat, and a rat.
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things needed to do this quickly and easily.

```
pd.Series.apply()
```

and

```
all()
```

Whence:

```
#apply a function to each row in the series
#the function returns true iff all the words in sample_list are in the value
#we use boolean indexing to only return the True values.
x[x.apply(lambda x: all([y in x for y in sample_list]))]
```

Which returns:

```
0     I have a dog, a cat, and a rat.
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

as required.